# Meld on Centos7 gives error: "TypeError: Couldn't find conversion for foreign struct 'cairo.Context'"

Tags: centos7, rhel7

On a Centos 7 host, we got this error when running meld (installed from Epel):

> TypeError: Couldn't find conversion for foreign struct 'cairo.Context'

On another system we observed a slightly different error:

> TypeError: Couldn't find foreign struct converter for 'cairo.Context'

The graphics appeared incomplete: no blue shapes to associate blocks of text. A web search returned only pages about Ubuntu, not RHEL 7 or Centos 7, hence this post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem disappeared when we installed the `pygobject3` package. Also the `pycairo` package needs to be installed (thanks @christophe-muller for mentioning this).

```
yum install pygobject3 pycairo
```

Comment: There were in fact two missing deps: installing the meld package did not install the pycairo package. Then installing the pycairo package did not install the pygobject3 package. :-(